# Strange artifacts on Blender painted texture after re-opening

Tags: mesh, texturing, armature

With some reason I've got strange lines on my finished texture. When I made it I didn't see it. When I re-opened the projects I saw the strange black/white lines on my object. [image: Look at the hand] [image: You asked for the UV and texture]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the UVs and the texture, it looks like you needed to increase Bleed beyond the UV faces while painting.

Comment: read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14979/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/fill-tool-not-respecting-the-boundaries-of-my-face-selection-mask/31276#31276

Comment: I think it isn't the problem, because the lines weren't there when I draw it, and the UV was there too. It only appeared when I re-opened it. Now it is appeared in Unity aswell. One more thing: It can be only seen from relatively far. If you stare it from close, you won't see them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) issue.

When painting the texture, Blender disables mipmapping (so everything looks shaper) so you don't notice the problem.

When you view the object from a distance, it's actually using a scaled down version of the texture, which shows the black background bleeding through, hence the wires. The solution is to increase Bleed.

You can also fix it in a 2D software using the 'maximum' filter.